# Find the duplicate element in an array of consecutive integers in O(log n) time

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, optimization, duplicates

A couple of days ago, in an interview I was asked for a program that would find the single duplicate element in a consecutive integer array in `O(log n)` time.

The case is somewhat specific, as there are a total of 11 integers (1 to 10, *in that order*) plus, a single duplicate of any of these numbers, inserted somewhere in between.

I was given a sample similar to this:

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, **2**, 7, 8, 9, 10}

So, now I've come up with the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a[11] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10}, first=0, last=10, mid;

    while (1)
    {
        mid = (first + last)/2;

        if (mid+1 == a[mid])
            first = mid+1;

        else if ((mid == 0) || (mid == 10) || (a[mid+1] - a[mid-1] == 1))   /* Order is Important, (a[mid+1] - a[mid-1] == 1) must be last */
            break;

        else
            last = mid-1;
    }

    printf("Duplicate element is %d, located at position no. %d.", a[mid], mid+1);

    return 0;
}
```

Would this properly satisfy the `O(log n)` criteria? And, are there any alternatives/improvements over this?

Comment: A tip: Always use half-open intervals. BTW: What about those magic numbers in the elseif-brnch?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it has `O(log n)` time complexity.

It is possible to make the code more clear using the following fact: you need to find the smallest `i` such that `a[i] != i + 1`, so it can be implemented in a more concise way:

```
//invariant: the [0...low] prefix does not contain a duplicate
//           the [0...high] prefix contains a duplicate
low = 0 //[0...0] prefix obviously does not contain a duplicate
high = 10 //the entire array obviously contains a duplicate
while high - low > 1:
    mid = (low + high) / 2 
    if a[mid] != mid + 1:
        high = mid
    else:
        low = mid
print(a[high], high)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can modify the `binary search algorithm` to get the solution. In `binary search`, we have a key and we used this key to find its position by bisecting the array size. Here, we don't have a key, instead we have to find it. But the behavior of `duplicate element` can be used to `bisect` the array size. How ? lets see:

On carefully looking the data, we can easily see that after inserting the duplicate element at random position (say `index`) in consecutive element array the property of elements will change (`a[i] == i+1` --> `a[i] != i+1`) from the position `index` (including the `index`). Now this changed property can be used to bisect the array size. Hence, we can find out the duplicate in `O(log(n))`.

For example, Consider your given array: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

```
{1,  2,  3,   4,  5,  6,  2,  7,  8,  9,  10}
                          ||
                          from this position the the property of (a[i] == i+1) will no more satisfied.
```

This property can be model to bisect the array size in solution.

```
void  binary_duplictae_finder(int a[], int low, int high) {

   int mid=(low+high)/2;

   if(high - low > 1){
          if(a[mid]!=mid+1)
              binary_duplictae_finder(a, low, mid);
          else
              binary_duplictae_finder(a, mid, high);
   }

   if(high==low+1)
      printf("%d ", a[high]);
 }
```